# Is it acceptable to return null from a factory constructor in Dart?

Tags: constructor, null, dart, factory

I've been writing some code in Dart.  I really love the factory constructor, but I'm afraid that I'm abusing it's usefulness.  In particular, when I write a value object class, I sometimes return null if the validation fails.

```dart
class EmailAddress {
  static final RegExp _regex = new RegExp(...);
  final String _value;

  factory EmailAddress(String input) {
    return _regex.hasMatch(input) ? new EmailAddress._internal(input) : null;
  }

  const EmailAddress._internal(this._value);

  toString() => _value;
}
```

At first, this doesn't seem all that bad.  However, when you actually use it, this is what you see.

```dart
methodThatCreatesAnEmailAddress() {
  var emailAddress = new EmailAddress("definitely not an email address");
  ...
}
```

The argument why this is bad is that a developer coming from another statically typed language, such as Java or C++, would expect `emailAddress` to always be initialized to a non-null value.  The argument why this is perfectly acceptable is that the constructor is factory and, as such, is allowed to return a `null` value.

So is this bad practice or taking advantage of a useful feature?

Comment: `return _regex.hasMatch(input) ? new EmailAddress._internal(input) : throw "something went wrong";` Also your "would expect emailAddress to always be initialized to a non-null value"  is not always possible if you expected the correct result from wrong passed arguments.

Comment: the validation of the email adress is not to be done in the constructor, but rather right when you ask it to the user. Validating as soon as possible, and informing user as soon as possible (for example, by disabling the 'send' button in this case) is the best practice.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With null-safe Dart, `factory` constructors are no longer permitted to return `null`.

[Existing `factory` constructors that return `null` are expected to be replaced with `static` methods when migrated](https://dart.dev/null-safety/faq#how-should-i-migrate-a-factory-that-can-return-null).

Answer (score 5):

Returning `null` value as result from a factory is acceptable because the builtin `factory` feature in Dart [Factory software concept](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(software_concept)) does not have any null-restriction.

On the other hand I can rephrase your question "Is it acceptable to return null from a equality operator"

```dart
bool operator ==(other) {
  return null;
}
```

This is also acceptable because there is no such restriction that this operator cannot return the `null` value.

But there is another question? Why do it and how to avoid it?

```dart
factory EmailAddress(String input) {
  return _regex.hasMatch(input) ? new EmailAddress._internal(input) :
    throw "something went wrong";
}
```

P.S.

My personal opinion that returning `null` from `factory` in Dart is a `bad practice` because factories in Dart are very difficult to distinguish from constructors.

From the outside they looks like constructors with the difference that they are more powerful because can construct different kinds of objects.

And they also have their restrictions but this is another story.

Comment: I agree with your opinion in this matter.  I'm considering something like `var emailAddress = new EmailAddress.fromString(input);`.  I think this is a bit more clear that this is in fact a factory constructor and the return value can be null.

Comment: Even for named constructors, I would consider this an anti-pattern. When I call a constructor with `new`, I don't expect `null`.

Comment: @Ganymede I'm curious: now that `new` is optional (and [is discouraged](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#dont-use-new)), does that change your opinion at all?  Even for named factory constructors?  Since those aren't distinguishable from `static` methods at callsites, do you also disapprove of having `static` methods return `null`?

Comment: This is not true anymore, with sound null safety a factory cannot anymore return null since dart 2.12

Answer (score 3):

It's bad practice. When someone calls a constructor they expect a non-null value.

For your case I might do validation in a static method:

```dart
class EmailAddress {
  final String _value;
  static final RegExp _regex = new RegExp(r"...");

  static bool isValid(String email) => _regex.hasMatch(email);

  EmailAddress(this._value) {
    if (!isValid(_value)) throw "Invalid email: $_value";
  }
}
```

Now you get code reuse and nice semantics. For instance:

```dart
querySelector("#sendButton").disabled = !EmailAddress.isValid(userEmail);
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to dissent from other answers: at least for *named* `factory` constructors, I don't see anything wrong with returning `null`.

[The main differences between a `factory` constructor and a `static` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52299408/179715) are that a `factory` constructor can be used with `new` and can be the unnamed, default constructor.  [Using `new` is now discouraged](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#dont-use-new), so a named `factory` constructor in most cases is not distinguishable from a `static` method invocation at a callsite.

I don't see anything wrong with a `static` method returning `null`, and therefore I don't see anything wrong with a named `factory` constructor returning `null` either.

If the `factory` constructor is *unnamed*, then I would agree that returning `null` is likely to be unexpected by the caller and probably should be avoided.

That said, in such cases, there isn't much reason to use a `factory` constructor over a `static` method, and a `static` method is clearer.

### Update

Using a `static` method to return `null` is the recommendation for code migrated to null-safety.  See [my new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66003907/).

Answer (score 2):

Please don't do this. As a user of a constructor I expect to receive an instance of the constructor's class. It's ok to return a pre-existing instance or an instance of a subtype in Dart, but don't return `null`.

I'd recommend one of two options to do what you want here:

1. throw an exception on invalid inputs. This way at least the error is early, rather than later if you've stored the `null` somewhere.
2. Use a static method instead of a constructor. Static methods can return `null` and not be as confusing.
3. Provide a fallback path, such as `int.parse` does. You can accept a callback that will be called on an error.

I prefer 1 or 3 myself. I'd like to know explicitly when something isn't valid.