# dart advantage of a factory constructor identifier

Tags: dart, flutter

I've been investigating JSON parsing for my Flutter app and have a question about factory constructors that I can't resolve. I'm trying to understand the advantage of using a factory constructor versus a plain constructor. For example, I see quite a few JSON parsing examples that create a model class with a JSON constructor like this:

```
class Student{
  String studentId;
  String studentName;
  int studentScores;

  Student({
    this.studentId,
    this.studentName,
    this.studentScores
  });

  factory Student.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){
    return Student(
      studentId: parsedJson['id'],
      studentName : parsedJson['name'],
      studentScores : parsedJson ['score']
    );
  }
}
```

I've also seen an equal number of examples that DON'T declare the constructor as a factory. Both types of classname.fromJSON constructors create an object from the JSON data so is there an advantage to declaring the constructor as a factory or is using a factory here superfluous?

Comment: Factory constructors are not actual constructors. They are functions hidden behind a fake constructor.  They are used to replace static methods that you'd use in other languages

Comment: This helped me understand it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56107639

Answer (score 62):

A normal constructor **always** returns a new instance of the current class (except when the constructor throws an exception).

A factory constructor is quite similar to a static method with the differences that it

- can only return an instance of the current class or one of its subclasses
- can be invoked with `new` but that is now less relevant since `new` became optional.
- has no initializer list (no `: super()`)

So a factory constructor can be used

- to create instances of subclasses (for example depending on the passed parameter
- to return a cached instance instead of a new one
- to prepare calculated values to forward them as parameters to a normal constructor so that final fields can be initialized with them. This is often used to work around limitations of what can be done in an initializer list of a normal constructor (like error handling).

In your example this code

```
  studentId: parsedJson['id'],
  studentName : parsedJson['name'],
  studentScores : parsedJson ['score']
```

could be moved to the body of a normal constructor because no `final` fields need to be initialized.

Comment: I think the main point of factory constructor is to hide the fact that it's a static function as an implementation detail; to provide a consistent way of instantiating objects

Comment: But that's much less relevant now with `new` being optional. The main advantage is that it's quite obvious when you look at the source of the class that it is to create or return an instance of the class in a special way.

Comment: You can't use it as a variable like you'd do with callbacks though. But yeah, with dart 2 the gain is limited

Comment: Maybe mention that subclasses can't `super.factory`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Gunter. It seems like using a factory constructor verses a named constructor has valid special case uses but shouldn't be used capriciously. The majority of examples I saw could be adequately addressed just using a named constructor but were using a factory constructor. In the example I used in my question it seems like the correct implementation would be this:  `Student.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) : studentId = parsedJson['id'], studentName = parsedJson['name'], studentScores = parsedJson['score'];`

Comment: Right, if you made the 3 fields in the class `final` it would look differently though.

Comment: The "has no initializer list" part doesn't make sense. Static methods (which is what you're comparing against in that section) don't have initializer lists either.

Comment: Also, I think other than being usable with `new`, perhaps the only thing a factory constructor can do that a static method *can't* is to be the unnamed, default constructor.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I'm looking at this [official example](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data), where all fields are final, and even in such case I can write a named constructor like mjordan is suggesting:
```Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) : userId = json['userId'], id = 
  json['id'], title = json['title'];```
so I wonder, what's the real reason to use a factory constructor instead? It's used in all the official examples for json parsing.

Comment: Code in initializer list can become hard to read, but I don't think there is any other argument not to use your approach. If you for example want to return a differrent subclass dependening on the JSON content, you're out of luck with initializer list. A factory method allows you to do `if ( json['kind'] == 'vinyl') return VinylAlbum(...)`

Comment: Ok, there is a lot of difference. But what is the basic meaning of this keyword? It looks like sugar without any obvious advantages.

Comment: You are right, now with `new` being optional there isn't much difference to static functions anymore.

Answer (score 54):

[In the particular example in the question, there's no advantage to using a `factory` constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56142750/).  It makes no difference to callers (there is no expectation to receive an already-existing object), and this particular `factory` constructor could have been a normal constructor that delegated to the main constructor instead.

In general, the `factory` keyword is not very useful and provides an advantage only in special circumstances.

---

### A factory constructor vs. a normal constructor

- A factory constructor *invokes* another constructor.
- Since a factory constructor does not directly create a new instance, it cannot use a constructor initializer list.
- A normal constructor always returns a new instance of the class.  A factory constructor is permitted to return an existing instance, an instance of a derived class, or `null`. (However, [some people dislike returning `null` from a factory constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21792489/is-it-acceptable-to-return-null-from-a-factory-constructor-in-dart).  Note that returning `null` from a factory constructor is disallowed with null-safety.)
- Due to the above, an extending class cannot invoke a factory constructor as the superclass constructor.  A class that provides only `factory` constructors therefore cannot be extended with derived classes.

### A factory constructor vs. a static method

- A factory constructor can be the unnamed, default constructor of a class.
- A factory constructor can be used with `new`. (But [using `new` is now discouraged](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#dont-use-new).)
- Until Dart 2.15, [constructors could not be used as tear-offs](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/216) (i.e., they could not be used as callbacks), whereas `static` methods could.
- Static methods can be `async`. (A factory constructor must return a type of its class, so it cannot return a `Future`.)
- Factory constructors can be declared `const`.
- In null-safe Dart, a factory constructor cannot return a nullable type.
- In generated dartdoc documentation, a factory constructor obviously will be listed in the "Constructors" section (which is prominently at the top) whereas a static method will be in the "Static Methods" section (which currently is buried at the bottom).

Comment: that doesn't really answer the question. You explain the difference between a factory constructor and a normal one, and a static method respectively. The question instead is about why to use factory constructor when parsing json, given in the official examples a new instance is always created within the factory constructor.

Comment: @Alessio This is a very well written answer, and he works in Dart for Google, +1 from me.

Comment: @iKeepChangingName that's ok, but I still keep my opinion that the answer is not actually answering the question, while been a well written summary of what a factory constructor is and isn't. The fact that he works in Dart for Google doesn't change my opinion either. No worries we can disagree about it :)

Comment: Didn't like the answers here. They are **too complicated and do not answer the main question** clearly. Found a good explanation to the specific question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63628949/12695188

Answer (score 4):

After I've been noticing and wondering the same, and given I don't think the other answers actually answer the question ("I've been investigating JSON parsing [...] I'm trying to understand the advantage of using a factory constructor verses a plain constructor"), here my try:

there's no advantage or difference that I could see or understand, when parsing json, in using a factory constructor instead of a plain constructor. I tried both, and both works fine, with all the types of parameters. I decided eventually to adopt the factory constructor, because of the convenience of how the code is written, and readability, but it's a matter  of choice and both will work fine in all the cases.

Answer (score -2):

One of the uses of factory constructor is, we can decide which instance to create, at run-time and move all the logic to the parent's factory constructor

let's say you have 1 parent class and 2 subclasses

```
class GolderRetriever extends Dog{
   GolderRetriever(String name):super(name);
}
```

```
class Labrador extends Dog{
  Labrador(String name):super(name);
}
```

Then we have the parent class

```
class Dog{
  final String name;
  Dog(this.name);
  
  
  factory Dog.createInstance({required String name,DogType type=DogType.UNKNOWN}){
    
    if(type==DogType.GOLDEN_RETRIEVER){
      return GolderRetriever(name);
    }
    else if(type==DogType.DALMATION){
      return Labrador(name);
    }else{
    return Dog(name);
    }
  }
}
```

and also I have enum DogType

```
enum DogType{
  GOLDEN_RETRIEVER,DALMATION,UNKNOWN
}
```

Then in the main Method, you just delegate which subclass instance you want to create to the parent Dog class

```
main() {
     
  Dog myDog = Dog.createInstance(name:"Rocky",type:DogType.DALMATION);
  Dog myNeighboursDog =  Dog.createInstance(name:"Tommy",type:DogType.GOLDEN_RETRIEVER);
  Dog strayDog = Dog.createInstance(name:"jimmy");
}
```

you can't do this with a named constructor as you can create only the instance of that class(Dog class), not its subtypes.

Now the responsibility of which instance to create is delegated to the parent class. This can remove a lot of if-else boilerplate code. When you want to change the logic, you just change that in Animal class alone.

Comment: First, I don't think that answers the question. Secondly, I don't think it is a good practise, that a parent class knows about its children. Your example would fit better, if `Dog` would be called `DogFactory` and there would be an additional `DogInterface`. `DogFactory` could then use the factory constructor build in into Dart.

Comment: The parent class shouldn't know about its children, Thank you, that makes a lot of sense!!!