# Understanding Factory constructor code example - Dart

Tags: constructor, dart

I have some niggling questions about factory constructors example mentioned here (https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#factory-constructors). 
I am aware of only three types of constructors on a basic level - default, named and parameterised.

1. Why should I use `factory` at all for this example?
2. Is that a named constructor which is being used? and why?
   [image: Example factory constructor]

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/52299304/

Answer (score 323, accepted):

**tl;dr** Use a factory in situations where you don't *necessarily* want to return a *new* instance of the class itself. Use cases:

- the constructor is expensive, so you want to return an existing instance - if possible - instead of creating a new one;
- you only ever want to create one instance of a class (the singleton pattern);
- you want to return a subclass instance instead of the class itself.

**Explanation**

A Dart class may have **generative constructors** or **factory constructors.** A generative constructor is a function that always returns a new instance of the class. Because of this, it does not utilize the `return` keyword. A common generative constructor is of the form:

```
class Person {
  String name;
  String country;

  // unnamed generative constructor
  Person(this.name, this.country);
}
var p = Person("...") // returns a new instance of the Person class
```

A factory constructor has looser constraints than a generative constructor. The factory need only return an instance that is the same type as the class or that implements its methods (ie satisfies its interface). This *could* be a new instance of the class, but could also be an existing instance of the class or a new/existing instance of a subclass (which will necessarily have the same methods as the parent). A factory can use control flow to determine what object to return, and must utilize the `return` keyword. In order for a factory to return a new class instance, it must first call a generative constructor.

[image: Dart Factory Explained]

In your example, the unnamed factory constructor first reads from a Map property called `_cache` (which, because it is `Static`, is stored at the class level and therefore independent of any instance variable). If an instance variable already exists, it is returned. Otherwise, a new instance is generated by calling the named generative constructor `Logger._internal`. This value is cached and then returned. Because the generative constructor takes only a `name` parameter, the `mute` property will always be initialized to false, but can be changed with the default setter:

```
var log = Logger("...");
log.mute = true;
log.log(...); // will not print
```

The term `factory` alludes to the Factory Pattern, which is all about allowing a constructor to return a subclass instance (instead of a class instance) based on the arguments supplied. A good example of this use case in Dart is the abstract HTML [Element class](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.3.0/dart-html/Element-class.html), which defines dozens of named factory constructor functions returning different subclasses. For example, `Element.div()` and `Element.li()` return `<div>` and `<li>` elements, respectively.

In this caching application, I find "factory" a bit of a misnomer since its purpose is to avoid calls to the generative constructor, and I think of real-world factories as inherently generative. Perhaps a more suitable term here would be "warehouse": if an item is already available, pull it off the shelf and deliver it. If not, call for a new one.

How does all this relate to named constructors? Generative and factory constructors can both be either unnamed or named:

```
...
  // named generative
  // delegates to the default generative constructor
  Person.greek(String name) : this(name, "Greece"); 

  // named factory 
  factory Person.greek(String name) {
    return Greek(name);
  }
}

class Greek extends Person {
  Greek(String name) : super(name, "Greece");
}
```

Comment: then what's the difference between static and factory??

Comment: `static` can refer to either class-wide methods or variables, whereas `factory` refers only to a constructor method. IOW, you cannot invoke a static method to construct an instance of a class, and you cannot invoke a factory method to do anything other than that. The only similarity is that they both do not have access to `this`.

Comment: `you cannot invoke a static method to construct an instance of a class` -- But what does `static A get instance() => A();` do, doesn't it return the instance of the class?

Comment: "you cannot invoke a static method to construct an instance of a class" - that's misleading because you can create static methods that return instances of the class. What he really meant to say there I think is that it's not the purpose of a static method. A few design patterns do use static methods for creating factories and some of those are a essentially obsolete with Dart's introduction of the factory keyword (perhaps obsolete is the wrong wording; basically you'd use a built-in language construct instead of static factory methods)

Answer (score 56):

1. There is not much difference between a static method and a factory constructor.

   For a factory constructor the return type is fixed to the type of the class while for a static method you can provide your own return type.

   A factory constructor can be invoked with `new`, but that became mostly irrelevant with optional `new` in Dart 2.

   There are other features like redirects rather rarely used that are supported for (factory) constructors but not for static methods.

   It is probably still good practice to use a factory constructor to create instances of classes instead of static methods to make the purpose of object creation more obvious.

   This is the reason a factory constructor is used in the example you posted and perhaps because the code was originally written in Dart 1 where it allowed to create a logger instance with `new` like with any other class.
2. Yes this is a named constructor and the prefix `_` makes it a private named constructor. Only named constructors can be made private because otherwise there would be no place to add the `_` prefix.

   It is used to prevent instance creation from anywhere else than from the public factory constructor. This way it is ensured there can't be more than one `Logger` instance in your application.
   The factory constructor only creates an instance the first time, and for subsequent calls always returns the previously created instance.

Comment: Sir, is your last line `The factory constructor only creates ... previously created instance` always true? I think it is on us how we handle the cache. A `factory` constructor *should* create an instance only once but can do it many times also, this is what I think. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks

Comment: This is just a possible use case if implemented this way, not a general truth. ("It is used to prevent ...")

Answer (score 37):

Complementing Dave's answer, this code shows a clear example when use factory to return a parent related class.

Take a look a this code from https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/from-java-to-dart/#3

You can run this code here. https://dartpad.dartlang.org/63e040a3fd682e191af40f6427eaf9ef

Make some changes in order to learn how it would work in certain situations, like singletons.

```
import 'dart:math';

abstract class Shape {
  factory Shape(String type) {
    if (type == 'circle') return Circle(2);
    if (type == 'square') return Square(2);
    // To trigger exception, don't implement a check for 'triangle'.
    throw 'Can\'t create $type.';
  }
  num get area;
}

class Circle implements Shape {
  final num radius;
  Circle(this.radius);
  num get area => pi * pow(radius, 2);
}

class Square implements Shape {
  final num side;
  Square(this.side);
  num get area => pow(side, 2);
}

class Triangle implements Shape {
  final num side;
  Triangle(this.side);
  num get area => pow(side, 2) / 2;
}

main() {
  try {
    print(Shape('circle').area);
    print(Shape('square').area);
    print(Shape('triangle').area);
  } catch (err) {
    print(err);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

In addition to the other answers, also consider the *order of instantiating objects* and when the instance is created:

In **normal constructor**, an instance gets created and the final variables get instantiated with the initializer list. This is why there's no `return` statement. The *instance to return is already fixed*, when executing the constructor!

In a **factory constructor**, the *instance to return is decided by the method*. That's why it needs a `return` statement and why it'll usually call a normal constructor in at least one path.

So a factory does nothing different than a static method could do (in other languages often called `getInstance()`), except you cannot overload the constructor with a static method but you can with a factory method. I.e. factory methods are a way to hide the fact that the user of your class is not calling a constructor but a static method:

```
// C++
MyCoolService.getInstance()

// Dart
MyCoolService()
```