# Why use factory when constructing a new instance from a map structure?

Tags: dart

I'm trying to really understand the flow of JSON data coming from an API until I can consume it as an object.

Now I think I have everything in place, my only question is why I see some people use the factory when they use the named constructor .fromJson.
According to the Dart documentation:

> we use the factory keyword when we implement a constructor that
> doesn't always create a new instance of your class.

But in this case, we always will make an instance when using fromJson, right?

Then why some people use:

```
   factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      User(name: json['name'], alias: json['alias']);
```

instead of the more reasonable:

```
  User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : name = json['name'],
        alias = json['alias'];
```

Thanks so much for any aclaration.

Comment: In some cases, such as if you're using `package:built_value` or `package:json_serializable` for JSON serialization (and you really should instead of doing it manually; doing proper error checks of JSON input is a lot of work), the class is abstract, `.fromJson` returns an instance of an implementation class, so it must be a `factory` constructor.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Making a public constructor a factory can be a *defensive* design, even when it's not technically required.

If you make a constructor generative, then someone, somewhere, might extend your class with a subclass and forward their constructor to your generative constructor.

At that point, it becomes a *breaking change* to make your constructor into a factory. If you decide you want more validation and it becomes more convenient if the constructor was a factory, you're now blocked from making the change.

Making a public constructor generative is a *promise* (so is making it `const`), so you're better of not doing it unless you actually *want* to. Don't expose public generative (or const) constructors by accident, or just because you can. Do it if you intend the class to be used as a super-class through that constructor. Otherwise it's safer to expose only a factory constructor, and keep the generative constructor private.

Comment: I understand it now, the reasons you give are very solid and well structured, thank you very much for such a good clarification lrn.

Answer (score 24):

Let me add some examples to lrn's helpful explanation.

Say you create a `User` class like so:

```dart
class User {
  User({this.name, this.alias});

  User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return User(name: json['name'], alias: json['alias']);
  }

  final String name;
  final String alias;
}
```

The `User.fromJson` constructor is a generative constructor. One characteristic of generative constructors is that you can forward to them from another constructor. That means someone else can subclass your class like so:

```dart
class SoftwareUser extends User {
  SoftwareUser(Map<String, dynamic> json) : super.fromJson(json);
}
```

The `super.fromJson(json)` part just forwards the parameter to your original constructor. So far so good.

But later you decide that you'd like to do a bit of error checking and text manipulation on that JSON map before you try to create an object from it. You can do a little with asserts but you're limited. Factory constructors, on the other hand, would allow you to do a lot more. Here's an example of doing a more work in the constructor:

```dart
class User {
  User({this.name, this.alias});

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    String userName = json['name'];
    String userAlias = json['alias'];
    if (userName == null || userAlias == null) throw FormatException();
    userName = userName.toUpperCase();
    userAlias = userAlias.toUpperCase();
    return User(name: userName, alias: userAlias);
  }

  final String name;
  final String alias;
}
```

That's great for the `User` class, but the problem is that now the `SoftwareUser` subclass is broken.

```dart
class SoftwareUser extends User {
  SoftwareUser(Map<String, dynamic> json) : super.fromJson(json); //   <-- error
}

// The constructor 'User User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)' 
// is a factory constructor, but must be a generative constructor 
// to be a valid superinitializer.
// 
// Try calling a different constructor of the superclass, or making 
// the called constructor not be a factory constructor.
```

As the error message says, you can't forward to a factory constructor.

If you had started with the factory constructor for `User` in the beginning, then the `SoftwareUser` subclass would never have been able to forward like that. The factory constructor would allow you to change from this:

```dart
factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      User(name: json['name'], alias: json['alias']);
```

to this:

```dart
factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  String userName = json['name'];
  String userAlias = json['alias'];
  if (userName == null || userAlias == null) throw FormatException();
  userName = userName.toUpperCase();
  userAlias = userAlias.toUpperCase();
  return User(name: userName, alias: userAlias);
}
```

without breaking any subclasses. That's why lrn called it defensive design. Even though you don't know your future needs, you'll be able to make internal changes to how the object is created later without breaking external dependencies.