# What advantages of factory constructor over standalone factory class or function?

Tags: dart, factory

I've just started learning Dart and I wonder what advantages of `factory constructor` over standalone factory class or function?

When we add new derived class then we need to change factory method inside of our abstract class, it is fine if we have its code, but if it comes with library - factory constructor becomes useless?

Or there is some mechanism to update factory method with info about derived classes? If it so, please share an example.

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52299304/dart-advantage-of-a-factory-constructor-identifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`factory` lets you return subtypes, which is very useful.

For instance, you could have `factory MyClass.empty => const _EmpytMyClass()` and return a trivial implementation with no storage.

You can also use it to returned cached values if you want to have canonical instances of your class.

You can also use `factory` to call methods to create your instances. See here: https://github.com/dart-lang/json_serializable/blob/4033f6ad4e3c96bc2ed16d93c0995e11fcfe42df/example/lib/example.dart#L29

Comment: I see, it's more useful for creating instances of the same class. Is there any way to update factory constructor, when I add new derived class?(for the cases when abstract class is in library)

Comment: Not sure if I follow your question. Can you give an example?

Comment: Given lib with `abstract class` and some concrete implementations. Abstract class have `factory costructor` which can construct these concrete implementations. When I add my own implementation, I need to update that factory constructor to support my class. Is there any way to do that or I need to implement standalone function for that?

Comment: Seems totally pointless though. Why not just use static function for this use case?