# Passing class static factory as method parameter in Dart

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm currently attempting to abstract making different HTTP requests by using generics. I'm using `json_serializale` for generating `fromJson()` and `toJson()` methods.

Here is a simple model file:

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'article.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Article {
  int id = 0;
  String title = "";

  Article({this.id, this.title});

  factory Article.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$ArticleFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ArticleToJson(this);
}
```

I have a generic class that needs to be passed the `fromJson`-method, see:

```
typedef CreateModelFromJson = dynamic Function(Map<String, dynamic> json);

class HttpGet<Model> {
  CreateModelFromJson createModelFromJson;

  HttpGet({
    this.createModelFromJson,
  });

  Future<Model> do() async {
    // [... make HTTP request and do stuff ...]
    return createModelFromJson(jsonData);
  }
}
```

And finally, here is the `ArticleService`:

```
class ArticleService {
  Future<Model> read() => HttpGet<Article>({
    createModelFromJson: Article.fromJson,
  }).do();
}
```

This underlines-in-red `fromJson` in `createModelFromJson: Article.fromJson,`, with the error being:

> The getter 'fromJson' isn't defined for the class 'Article'.
>   Try importing the library that defines 'fromJson', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'fromJson'.dart(undefined_getter)

Obviously the compiler believes `.fromJson` to be a static field. However, it's, as can be seen above, a static factory method.

1.) Can you help with how to pass the constructor to the generic class?

**ALSO:**
2.) I'm not sure whether I'll actually get an `Article` back, or if I have to type cast it first? I'm kind of worried about the `dynamic` return type of the `typedef`.

3.) I'm also open for better ideas for what I'm attempting to do.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As of [Dart 2.15](https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-2-15-7e7a598e508a), Dart now supports constructor tear-offs.  Named constructors can be used as expected.  The default, unnamed constructor for a class named `ClassName` can be referenced with `ClassName.new`. (`ClassName` by itself would be a reference to the corresponding `Type` object.)

---

[Dart 2.14 and earlier did not allow using constructors as tear-offs](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/10659).  For those versions, I recommend [using a `static` method instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54997386/179715).

Alternatively you could just create an explicit closure:

```
class ArticleService {
  Future<Model> read() => HttpGet<Article>({
    createModelFromJson: (json) => Article.fromJson(json),
  }).do();
}
```

Comment: This is absolutely amazing. Man, I was tearing my hair out over this. I went with the static method, like you recommended. However, the explicit closure is a neat trick to have in one's bag of tools. Thank you very much, @jamesdlin!