# Pass a class as method parameter in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Suppose this class:

```
class SimpleRectPaint extends Object {

  static CustomPaint build( ParamsBundle paramBundle ) {
     return CustomPaint(
         painter: SimpleRectPainter( paramBundle: paramBundle ),
         child: Container(width: paramBundle.width, height: paramBundle.height)
     );
  }

}
```

I'd like to abstract the class `SimpleRectPaint` by means of a `ClassReference` parameter `someClass` and make the method more generic. Unfortunately, this isn't valid code:

```
class SimpleRectPaint extends Object {

  static CustomPaint build( ParamsBundle paramBundle, ClassReference someClass ) {
     return CustomPaint(
         painter: someClass( paramBundle: paramBundle ),
         child: Container(width: paramBundle.width, height: paramBundle.height)
     );
  }

}
```

**Q: How do I have to write it instead?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing class static factory as method parameter in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55962139/passing-class-static-factory-as-method-parameter-in-dart)

Comment: @jamesdlin Thx! Will review tomorrow. Too late. I'm aware, that I may pass in a closure of signature ( paramBundle -> someClass ). But somehow I don't like it. Hm...

Comment: I question the benefit of abstracting it this way. Surely any place that can call that static method has access to both the `ParamsBundle` and the class reference that gets constructed using the `ParamsBundle` as its parameter, so why wouldn't you just construct that class beforehand and pass in the constructed object? What do you gain by having the `build` method be responsible for the construction?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You could do that by passing a `CustomPainterCreator`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Generic Painter',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyWidget(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: SizedBox(
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        child: Stack(
          fit: StackFit.expand,
          children: [
            Background(),
            MyPainter(creator: RectPainter.creator, color: Color(0xFF104C91)),
            MyPainter(creator: OvalPainter.creator, color: Color(0xFF1F8AC0)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Background extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Color(0xFFEFC9AF),
        border: Border.all(width: 3.0),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
      ),
    );
  }
}

typedef CustomPainterCreator(Color color);

class MyPainter extends StatelessWidget {
  final CustomPainterCreator creator;
  final Color color;

  const MyPainter({
    Key key,
    this.creator,
    this.color,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomPaint(
      painter: creator(color),
    );
  }
}

class OvalPainter extends CustomPainter {
  static CustomPainterCreator creator = (color) => OvalPainter(color: color);

  final Color color;

  OvalPainter({this.color = Colors.green});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()..color = color;
    canvas.drawOval(
      Rect.fromLTWH(size.width * .4, size.height * .15, size.width * .5,
          size.height * .5),
      paint,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(OvalPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}

class RectPainter extends CustomPainter {
  static CustomPainterCreator creator = (color) => RectPainter(color: color);

  final Color color;

  RectPainter({this.color = Colors.indigo});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()..color = color;
    canvas.drawRRect(
      RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
          Rect.fromLTWH(size.width * .15, size.height * .25, size.width * .6,
              size.height * .6),
          Radius.circular(20)),
      paint,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(RectPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

But, though the exercise is interesting... Why?

Instead of:

```
MyPainter(creator: RectPainter.creator, color: Color(0xFF104C91)),
```

You can just do:

```
CustomPaint(painter: RectPainter(color: Color(0xFF104C91))),
```

If, not, what is the specific needs that would require more abstraction?