# Book: Flutter Apprentice - Try to make a generic ModelConverter from a Api Response

Tags: flutter, dart, generics, jsonconverter, chopper

In the excellent Flutter [book](https://www.raywenderlich.com/books/flutter-apprentice/v1.0.ea2) by **Raywenderlich**, **Chapter 13** is dedicated to obtaining Responses from an api using libraries **Chopper** and **JsonConverter**.

The code in Github is [here](https://github.com/raywenderlich/flta-materials/tree/editions/1.0/13-using-the-chopper-library/projects/final)

He also proposes the use of a response wrapper like functional programming, of the type Success/Error.

The ModelConverter from Response to Success/Error wrapper, applies to the APIRecipeQuery model and only uses one method in one line `final recipeQuery = APIRecipeQuery.fromJson(mapData);`. It seems quite logical to make a generic convert, since it is a very useful class.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:chopper/chopper.dart';

import 'model_response.dart';
import 'recipe_model.dart';

class ModelConverter implements Converter {
  @override
  Request convertRequest(Request request) {
    // Add a header to the request that says you have a request type of application/json using jsonHeaders.
    // These constants are part of Chopper.
    final req = applyHeader(
      request,
      contentTypeKey,
      jsonHeaders,
      override: false,
    );

    return encodeJson(req);
  }

  @override
  Response<BodyType> convertResponse<BodyType, InnerType>(Response response) {
    return decodeJson<BodyType, InnerType>(response);
  }

  Request encodeJson(Request request) {
    final contentType = request.headers[contentTypeKey];
    // Confirm contentType is of type application/json.
    if (contentType != null && contentType.contains(jsonHeaders)) {
      return request.copyWith(body: json.encode(request.body));
    }
    return request;
  }

  Response decodeJson<BodyType, InnerType>(Response response) {
    final contentType = response.headers[contentTypeKey];
    var body = response.body;
    if (contentType != null && contentType.contains(jsonHeaders)) {
      body = utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes);
    }
    try {
      final mapData = json.decode(body);
      if (mapData['status'] != null) {
        return response.copyWith<BodyType>(
            body: Error(Exception(mapData['status'])) as BodyType);
      }
/*
The only line is next
*/
      final recipeQuery = APIRecipeQuery.fromJson(mapData);
      return response.copyWith<BodyType>(
          body: Success(recipeQuery) as BodyType);
    } catch (e) {
      chopperLogger.warning(e);
      return response.copyWith<BodyType>(body: Error(e) as BodyType);
    }
  }
```

So, I have tried by passing the model in the constructor as a parameter:

```dart
class ModelConverter <T extends JsonConverter> implements Converter {
  final T model;
  ModelConverter ({@required this.model});
```

and
I invoke it in `recipe_service.dart` with `converter: ModelConverter(model: APIRecipeQuery)`, but I don't know how to reference the model statically, and  can't access the method `model.fromJson`

Next, I have tried passing just the function converter:

```dart
class ModelConverter implements Converter {
  Function fromJson;
  ModelConverter ({@ required this.fromJson});
```

with a getter in the API, and in `recipe_service.dart` with `converter: ModelConverter(fromJson: APIRecipeQuery.fjConverter)`

```dart
class APIRecipeQuery {
  static Function get fjConverter => _ $ APIRecipeQueryFromJson;
```

But I can't get it to work.

What would be the best approach to make the ModelConverter generic?
Thnks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Solved in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55962139/passing-class-static-factory-as-method-parameter-in-dart)

model_converter.dart

```dart
. . .
typedef CreateModelFromJson = dynamic Function(Map<String, dynamic> json);

class ModelConverter<Model> implements Converter {
  final CreateModelFromJson fromJson;

  ModelConverter({@required this.fromJson});
. . .
  final query = fromJson(mapData) as Model;
. . .
```

and recipe_service.dart

```
. . .
      converter: ModelConverter<APIRecipeQuery>(
        fromJson: (json) => APIRecipeQuery.fromJson(json),
      ),
. . .
```