# What is the purpose of the factory keyword in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, factory

While looking at Reso Coder's TDD Clean Architecture tutorial, I came across some factory code that seems to do the same thing as a normal method. What's the benefit of using the factory keyword, and is there a difference between:

```
  factory NumberTriviaModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return NumberTriviaModel(
      text: json['text'],
      number: (json['number'] as num).toInt(),
    );
  }
```

and

```
NumberTriviaModel NumberTriviaFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return NumberTriviaModel(
      text: json['text'],
      number: (json['number'] as num).toInt(),
    );
  }
```

?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52299304/dart-advantage-of-a-factory-constructor-identifier this?

Comment: I see, thanks. So in this case the factory keyword is not necessary. But in more complex cases it could be used to return an instance of a subclass or return an existing object from a cache

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dart advantage of a factory constructor identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52299304/dart-advantage-of-a-factory-constructor-identifier)