# Flutter named constructor and private constructor

Tags: flutter, dart

What is a named constructor, the private constructor in Flutter?

in what scenario these are used in Flutter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main idea behind having **named constructors** in `Dart` is so that you can define multiple constructors for one class. You can only define one **unnamed constructor**, which is used like this:

```
Foo(...);
```

But what if you want alternative ways of instantiating `Foo`? A **named constructor** lets you do this:

```
Foo.bar(...);
Foo.baz(...);
```

Let's use the `Border` class in `Flutter` as an example. `Border` provides four constructors (one unnamed and three named).

```
Border                   // unnamed

Border.all               // named
Border.fromBorderSide    // named
Border.symmetric         // named
```

Each constructor provides an easier way to customize the `Border`. For example, the `Border.all` constructor applies the one set arguments to the entire set of borders of another widget (left border, top border, right border, and bottom border). So, in the case of the `Border` class, these constructors provide a more specific and lightweight way of creating a border.

We can then consider an example of when we might need to use named constructors over the unnamed version. Let's say we have data that represents a news story that we are going to display inside of a widget:

The unnamed constructor could look something like this:

```
Story({
  this.headline,
  this.publisher,
  this.publicationDateTime,
});
```

This works for general purposes, but what if you want to also be able to pass it a `JSON` response from an API? We might want to consider using a named constructor for this so that it can handle both parsed and unparsed data.

```
Story.fromJSON(this.jsonData);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read about factory constructors in [Official Documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#constructors) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52299304/dart-advantage-of-a-factory-constructor-identifier).

In your case, `createInstance` is a private constructor that can only be using inside DatabaseHelper class. Named constructors may be used for return created (cached) instances (performance).

Also, Google team created guides for introduction to Dart other platform developers. You can find tutorials like [Intro to Dart for Java Developers](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/from-java-to-dart) on [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs) page.