# What is the sence of factory constructor?

Tags: dart

This is a piece of external code I work with.

```
class Entry {
  const Entry({this.entry, @required this.entryId});

  final String entryId;
  final String entry;

  factory Entry.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Entry(entry: json['entry'], entryId: json['entryId']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {'entry': entry, 'entryId': entryId};
  }
}
```

What is a purpose of `factory` there?
It's not a singleton pattern usage, then what is it?
The named constructor `Entry.fromJson` just creates an instance of `Entry` from json values, then what  is the `factory` keyword meaning?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61590219/7015400

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you look at the manual, it says

> Use the factory keyword when implementing a constructor that doesn’t always create a new instance of its class. For example, a factory constructor might return an instance from a cache, or it might return an instance of a subtype. **Another use case for factory constructors is initializing a final variable using logic that can’t be handled in the initializer list.**

And that is exactly what you are doing. You want to have two `final` fields (entryId and entry) that need to be initialized in the declaration, from the constructors parameters or in the initializer list. But you want to apply some logic to the parameters to get their contents and that is only possible in the body. So you need a factory constructor, a normal constructor would not be able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

From dart manual

Factory constructors

Use the factory keyword when implementing a constructor that doesn’t always create a new instance of its class. For example, a factory constructor might return an instance from a cache, or it might return an instance of a subtype. Another use case for factory constructors is initializing a final variable using logic that can’t be handled in the initializer list.