# How to return and persist the null in a factory constructor?

Tags: flutter, dart, factory

I have a problem with the migration to *null-safety* of flutter, I know that in a factory it should no longer `return null` so I `return throw ArgumentError("")`, however in my services I bring the value of **canvas** as **null** and that is where it sends the error, but what I want is to continue the application and leave that value as **null**.

To explain it better; I have two models, **ModelA** has a variable called `canva` of type **ModelB**. When I send a data mapping to **ModelA**, from the server the variable `canva` arrives **null**, so it enters a condition and gives an error.

**ModelA** :

```
class ModelA extends A {
   ModelA ({
       required ModelB? background,
       required ModelB? canvas,
     }) : super(
            background,
            canvas,
   );

    factory ModelA.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic>? map) {
        if (map == null) throw ArgumentError('ModelA map must not be null');
    
        return ModelA(
           background: ModelB.fromMap(map['background']), // go in with not-null service value
           canvas: ModelB.fromMap(map['canvas']), // go in with null service value
        );
      }
}
```

**ModelB** :

```
class ModelB extends B {
    ModelB({
        String? content,
      }) : super(
              content;
            );


    factory ModelB.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic>? map) {
        // * before the migration null-safety
        // if (map == null) return null
        if (map == null) throw ArgumentError('ModelB map must not be null'); // enter here (error)
    
        return ModelB(
          content: map['content'],
        );
      }
}
```

After the error, I enter my application without any problem, but it doesn't run any more my function...

This is where I do the programming to save and return my complete **ModelA**.

```
final someList = List<ModelA>.from(
        listFromServer.where((i) {
          return (i['someType'] == 1));
        }).map(
          (i) {
            print("enter here");
            final isBackOrCan = i['background'] ?? i['canvas'];
            if (isBackOrCan != null) {
              newListModelB
                  .add(ModelB.fromMap(isBackOrCan));
            }
            return ModelA.fromMap(i); // enter here the map background not null and also the canva null
          },
        ),
      );

[ ... more code that i want to continue ...]

} catch (e) {
      print(e); // the message
      throw CacheException();
}
```

**Error :**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to preserve the old behavior of returning `null`, just use a `static` method instead of a `factory` constructor. ([`factory` constructors provide almost no advantages to `static` methods anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54997386/).) That would be the simplest and most straightforward fix.

But if you really want to disallow `null`, then `ModelA.fromMap` and `ModelB.fromMap` should require `map` to be non-nullable in the first place, and then you would need to proceed up the call chain to make callers check for `null` values.  In your case:

```dart
class ModelA extends A {
  ModelA({
    required ModelB? background,
    required ModelB? canvas,
  }) : super(
          background,
          canvas,
        );

  factory ModelA.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    var background = map['background'];
    var canvas = map['canvas'];
    return ModelA(
      background: background == null
          ? null
          : ModelB.fromMap(background), // go in with not-null service value
      canvas: canvas == null
          ? null
          : ModelB.fromMap(canvas), // go in with null service value
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! it works like that, just a question, now if the whole map comes null, how would you return its value so you don't get an error ?