# Best way to get value from future in constructor in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await, future

what ways you suggest for getting value from future in object constructor ?

```
class F{
late SomeObj<t> _obj;
F(){
 () async{
    _obj = await someFuture();
  }.call();
}
 somefunc() => doing something with _obj

}
```

but this doesn't gave me right res in the right time,
Other ways for this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Here are two possible approaches:

- Make your class's constructor private and force callers to instantiate your class via an asynchronous `static` method.  From the perspective of callers, [there is little difference between calling a `static` method and a named constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54997386/).

  ```dart
  class F {
    late SomeObj<T> _obj;

    F._();

    static Future<F> create() async {
      var f = F._();
      f._obj = await someFuture();
      return f;
    }

    Object? someFunc() => doSomethingWith(_obj);
  }
  ```
- Explicitly make everything that depends on the asynchronous value also asynchronous.  If `_obj` is initialized asynchronously, then `_obj` should be a `Future`.  If `someFunc` depends on `_obj`, then `someFunc` should return a `Future`.

  ```dart
  class F {
    Future<SomeObj<T>> _obj;

    F() : _obj = someFuture();

    Future<Object?> someFunc() async => doSomethingWith(await _obj);
  }
  ```