# What's the difference between a factory constructor and a named constructor or method?

Tags: flutter, dart, oop, factory

I can't understand the real purpose of factory constructors. I have this code that contains a method and a factory constructor:

```dart
  User fromJJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    final user = User(
      userName: json['userName'],
      photoUrl: json['photoUrl'],
      lastSeen: json['lastSeen'],
      active: json['active'],
    );
    user._id = json['id'];
    return user;
  }

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    final user = User(
      userName: json['userName'],
      photoUrl: json['photoUrl'],
      lastSeen: json['lastSeen'],
      active: json['active'],
    );
    user._id = json['id'];
    return user;
  }
```

What's the difference between the two above, they serve the exact same purpose, so what do factory constructors really do ?

Comment: Your above example does have any named constructor.  `fromJJson` is an *instance* method and would need to be invoked on an existing `User` object.  Usage of `fromJJson` and `User.fromJson` therefore would be different at call sites.  If `fromJJson` were a `static` method, then there would be no substantial difference in this case.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54997386/

Answer (score -1):

**A factory constructor does not Create instance of the class it just return an existing instance of the class.**

> Example of a factory constructor

```
class Animal{
  String name;
  String color;

  factory Animal.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Animal(json['name'], json['color']);
  }
}
```

> Example of a named constructor

```
class Animal{
   String name;
   String color;

  Person(this.name, this.color);

  Person.fromName(String name)
      : this(name, "Black");

  Person.fromColor(int color)
      : this("Unknown", color);

}
```

Comment: So the factory constructors always uses an already created object ? It can't create an object on it's own ?

Comment: No, a factory constructor can also create and return a new object

Comment: So what's the difference between the two ? I didn't understand yet the difference

Comment: Factory constructor is a static method which creates & returns instance of class, While named constructor is a type of constructor whose name can be other than the class name